# Webview in react-native doesn't get displayed with another jsx tag, but gets displayed alone

Tags: javascript, webview, react-native, navigator

I am using the NavigatorIOS and WebView to understand navigation.

I am not able to view the WebView in here, but if I just keep the WebView tag, it works. It doesn't work along with Text tag. Also, I do understand that the render function should return one tag and I am enclosing the two tags within the View tag.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NavigatorIOS,
  WebView,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  ScrollView
} = React;

var FirstPage = React.createClass({
  _handleChangePage() {
    this.props.toggleNavBar();
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: "Second Page",
      component: SecondPage,
      passProps: {
        toggleNavBar: this.props.toggleNavBar,
      }
    });

  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>FirstPage</Text>

        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this._handleChangePage}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Go to SecondPage</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var SecondPage = React.createClass({
  _handleChangePage() {
    this.props.toggleNavBar();
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: "First Page",
      component: FirstPage,
      passProps: {
        toggleNavBar: this.props.toggleNavBar,
      }
    });

  },

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <ScrollView>
            <Text> Some Text </Text> 
            <WebView 
              url={'https:www.google.com'}
              scalesPageToFit={true}
            />
            </ScrollView>
            </View>
    );
  }
});

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      navigationBarHidden: false
    };
  },

  toggleNavBar() {
    this.setState({
      navigationBarHidden: !this.state.navigationBarHidden
    });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS ref="nav"
                    itemWrapperStyle={styles.navWrap}
                    style={styles.nav}
                    initialRoute={{
                      title: "First Page",
                      component: FirstPage,
                      passProps: {
                        toggleNavBar: this.toggleNavBar,
                      }
                    }} />
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navWrap: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 70
  },
  nav: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: "#009DDD",
    padding: 10,
    margin: 10,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "#fff"
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);

module.exports = SampleApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of additional issues with the code you posted.

The react and react native modules are included incorrectly. I recommend changing it to:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NavigatorIOS,
  WebView,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';
```

The way you had it causes errors because `createClass` should be accessed from the *react* package.

The `url` prop on the `<WebView />` has been deprecated as of react native 0.20. I'd recommend upgrading react native and using the `source` prop instead.

Finally, based on your code sample it looks like you simply want to display a static text string above your web view. This removes the need for placing a `<ScrollView />` around it. This snippet will get your view to display properly. I used an inline style on the `<View />` for brevity sake. Note that I've preserved your use of the `url` prop from your original code sample:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <Text> Team WalmartLabs </Text> 
  <WebView 
    url={'https://www.google.com'}
    scalesPageToFit={true}
  />
</View>
```